# Is it possible to duplicate keyframes to multiple bones?

Tags: animation, keyframes

Do I really have to animate all four legs of an animal one by one if their motion is identical, or is there a way of animating just one leg and then copying all the animation keyframes to the other four?

I understand that some of their parameters might have to change (such as position on X and Y axis), but those parameters can easily be changed. It would take much longer to animate every single leg by hand than to just change a couple of coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select a **source bone**
2. open a **graph editor**
3. select **all keyframes** you want **to copy**
4. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
5. select the destination bone
6. set the cursor at the appropriate position
7. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>